# How to make Windows drag continuously with a touchpad like Mac's do?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, windows-10-v1909

On Mac OS X you can double click on the touchpad and start "dragging". If you get to the end of the touchpad you can use another finger to continue the "dragging" while the original finger continues to "touch" the touchpad.

My question is, can Windows machine's be configured to behave this way?
I have a Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.657)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable Click-Lock, a feature similar to that of Mac that enables users to continue dragging even after they have reached the edge of the touchpad by lifting their finger up without deselecting the item currently being dragged and without it moving back to it’s original position, follow these steps:-

1. Open settings
2. In the devices section, select Mouse/TrackPad.
3. Click on the additional settings link which would be highlighted in blue.
4. You will see the following window.

[image]

5. Enabling the clicklock will help in dragging and dropping once you reach the edge of the touchpad.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has them. Here's what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7RVF.png

Comment: @neubert Turn the clicklock on, see if it makes it work the way you wish.